# Upload file using Requests Library in Robot Framework

Tags: python-requests, xmlhttprequest, automated-tests, robotframework

I'm trying to upload a PDF file through Requests Library in Robot Framework, but the file doesn't get upload.

Whereas, when I tried the same in `Insomnia` it was work well (echo `complete` after successful upload).

Test case -

```
 *** Variables ***

 &{headers_file}    X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest

 *** Test Case ***

 &{file}    Create Dictionary    file    ${CURDIR}/test_certificate_report.pdf    flowChunkNumber    1    flowChunkSize    1048576    flowCurrentChunkSize    25020    flowTotalSize    25020    flowIdentifier    25020-test_certificate_reportpdf    flowFilename    test_certificate_report.pdf    flowRelativePath
        ...    test_certificate_report.pdf    flowTotalChunks    1
 ${test_uri}    Set Variable    /certificates/upload/7d5ebc7a-9ec4-444a-b2c1-f59e03999e58
 ${response}    POST On Session    api_reviewer_second    ${test_uri}    files=&{file}    headers=&{headers_file}
```

Output Log-

```
POST Request : url=https://api.company.net/certificates/upload/7d5ebc7a-9ec4-444a-b2c1-f59e00488e58 
               path_url=/certificates/upload/7d5ebc7a-9ec4-444a-b2c1-f59e03999e58 
               headers={'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.25.1', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=guk1a2tlmpij9l3re9ge01lva5', 'Content-Length': '1303', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=f6820b677ad526bf76b0258616c3f9e4'} 
               body=b'--f6820b677ad526bf76b0258616c3f9e4\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file"\r\n\r\nC:\\RobotFramework\\bDATA_Test/support_files/test_certificate_report.pdf\r\n--f6820b677ad526bf76b0258616c3f9e4\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="flowChunkNumber"; filename="flowChunkNumber"\r\n\r\n1\r\n--f6820b677ad526bf76b0258616c3f9e4\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="flowChunkSize"; filename="flowChunkSize"\r\n\r\n1048576\r\n--f6820b677ad526bf76b0258616c3f9e4\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="flowCurrentChunkSize"; filename="flowCurrentChunkSize"\r\n\r\n25020\r\n--f6820b677ad526bf76b0258616c3f9e4\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="flowTotalSize"; filename="flowTotalSize"\r\n\r\n25020\r\n--f6820b677ad526bf76b0258616c3f9e4\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="flowIdentifier"; filename="flowIdentifier"\r\n\r\n25020-test_certificate_reportpdf\r\n--f6820b677ad526bf76b0258616c3f9e4\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="flowFilename"; filename="flowFilename"\r\n\r\ntest_certificate_report.pdf\r\n--f6820b677ad526bf76b0258616c3f9e4\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="flowRelativePath"; filename="flowRelativePath"\r\n\r\ntest_certificate_report.pdf\r\n--f6820b677ad526bf76b0258616c3f9e4\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="flowTotalChunks"; filename="flowTotalChunks"\r\n\r\n1\r\n--f6820b677ad526bf76b0258616c3f9e4--\r\n' 
    
POST Response : url=https://api.company.net/certificates/upload/7d5ebc7a-9ec4-444a-b2c1-f59e03999e58
                status=200, reason=OK 
                headers={'Date': 'Thu, 15 Apr 2021 09:19:08 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Server': 'nginx', 'X-Powered-By': 'PHP/7.2.34', 'Expires': 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Type, Authorization', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, PATCH, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://app.company.net', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Content-Security-Policy': "default-src 'self' *.company.net; img-src *", 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000;'} 
                body=None
```

Can anyone please help me to identify the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Replace with these lines

```
${file}=    Get File For Streaming Upload    ${CURDIR}/test_certificate_report.pdf
${response}=    POST On Session    api_reviewer_second    ${test_uri}    data=${file}    headers=&{headers_file}
```